Is this biochem/molecular biology q about coronavirus replication fidelity appropriate for biology SE?
This question currently on Chemistry SE has received a poor reception there, partly because it falls into the domain of molecular/structural biology/biochemistry:

How do coronaviruses avoid the end replication problem?
As far as I am aware they have no telomerase, so how do they replicate the ends of their genome?
I am aware that viruses do mutate often. However if they had no means of replicating the end of their genome it would become shorter with each replication and eventually could not replicate at all.

Is this biochem/molecular biology q about coronavirus replication fidelity appropriate for biology SE? If there are other perceived shortcomings that would suggest it is not appropriate, what are they?

Yes, it's appropriate.
Questions are best received here when they explicitly demonstrate research effort, like linking to sources that motivate the question and/or support any assumptions made.
This helps us avoid questions where the answers necessarily pick apart at the premise of the question rather than, well, answering it.

Thanks for your feedback. As the comment section to the post shows there were useful discussions but it's better sent here where the question might be clarified further. An interesting angle is that telomeres and viral replication are evolutionarily related so share mechanisms of action in common.
